# How to interpret the "power up" section of the Atlas of Brauer Characters

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

How does one interpret the "Power Up" section of the Atlas of Finite Group Representations? For example, in the sporadic group $CO_2$ there are two conjugacy classes of elements of order $23$: $23A$ and $23B$. In the Power Up column of $23A$, one finds $23B^5$ and in the Power Up column of $23B$, one finds $23A^5$. What does $23B^5$ mean?

Comment: I would guess that what this means is that the elements of $23A$ are the fifth powers of elements of $23B$ and *vice versa*. Note that $5$ is the least quadratic non-residule modulo $23$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I also thought that might be the case.. Thanks for your comment!